# In WPF, use the DesignTime to set the Text of a TextBlock only when creating the UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, designer

```
<UserControl x:Class="MachineStatusPlugin.MachineStatus_UC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Mode=OneTime}"
             d:DesignHeight="7">
```

I want to use something similar to DesignHeight and DesignWidth to set the Text of a TextBlock, the Content of a Button, and the Content of a Label only during design time. Is this possible? I haven't been able to find any documentation as to what the attached properties are that can be modified with `System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty`

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock>
    <d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Hi Designer" />
        </Style>
    </d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>
</TextBlock>
```